# Massive problem with MiKTeX - cannot truely reinstall

Tags: miktex, installing, miktex-update

I am in the middle of my thesis and, full closure, I actually do not intend do reinstall my whole system (I am using Win10) and my thesis requires a lot of other porgramms with even bigger setup issues than TexStudio/Miktex2.9.

I got problems a couple of days ago using TexStudio. Different things actually, I lost track of them.

However I decided to reinstall both. BUT I cannot truely uninstall MiKTeX since it is visible AFTER uninstall and reboot in "Apps&Features". When trying to uninstall the remaining entry I get the following error

[image]

(For those who arent able to speak german it says [...not found. Make sure using the right name and try again.])

If I keep moving and install MiKTeX anyway, the installation is working fine, but when updating with 'Miktex Update' I do receive this error

[image]

Google is not quite a help, unless I am not able to use the right keywords.
I realy do appreciate any help I can get. I am very desperate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, why did you try to reinstall MiKTeX if TeXStudio makes problems? Which problems did you get?

You did not descibe exactly what you did to reinstall MiKTeX so we can only guess what could happen.

To (re-)install MiKTeX please follow theese steps:

1. Open system control panel in Windows 10, choose program deinstallation and deinstall MiKTeX 2.9. After finishing this
2. **Reboot** the computer
3. Now download the (I recommend) netinstaller from the MiKTeX homepage to install the complete MiKTeX.
4. Start the netinstaller the first time to download all needed files and
5. Restart the netinstaller to install MiKTeX with the downloaded files on your computer.
6. **Reboot** the computer
7. **Run the installed Package Manger** to be sure all packages are up to date!
8. **Reboot** the computer
9. Now install TeXStudio.

Comment: Alright, I am sorry for any confusing information.
First: I did follow you instructions, but after step 2 (reboot), I did find another entry within the system control panel called MikTex but without the "Miktex-Icon"....and whenever I am trying to uninstall this entry the error in picture 1 appears...
On the other hand I dont quite know why, but I got problems with different packages...full disclosure, I do not know anymore why and what kind of problems.

Comment: One of the last errors in TexStudio was "Syntax Error (8698): Unknown Filter 'DTCDecode' ". But once again...there appeared several errors out of nowhere (I do know, thats not what happend) and I was quite in a hurry. Right now I am unable to reproduce any errors

Comment: @Djiwahwah Then please try to deinstall in system control this another entry. If that does not work, get its PID-code and use Windows-Dos-command kill to end the process. Is someone around you knowing Windows system? Ask for Help then! Could it be you have problems with your OS?

Comment: The DTCDecode error is probably from an older bug that has been resolved (https://sourceforge.net/p/miktex/bugs/2605/). The rest sounds a bit as if you mixed up user and admin installation. You could try to install miktex in single user mode in some folder outside `C:\program files`.  Or install texlive.

Comment: But that is something I can handle until I will reset windows itself. Thanks to your help @Ulrike Fischer as well!