# Latex with full style packages

Tags: styles

I have been learning latex for mathematics journal typing for a while now. I installed and I've been able to do just a little because of problems like missing styles e.g. enumitem, fancy, etc. These problems have slowed down my progress on learning the writing software. Please, I need a guide on how to install with full style packages and if there's any guide you can give me. Thanks. I'm using Windows 10, with miktex 2.9 and texstudio installed.

Comment: Hope you installed the basic version, please download the complete version and try...

Comment: Start the miktex console and install everything that is missing.

Comment: Please see my answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/397068/16550 If you are lucky (depends on what you did before to install MiKTeX, used admin or user mode?) you can use TeXStudio after reinstalling complete MiKTeX. If not the easiest way is to delete TeXStudio and install the current version (it can then do a self-configuration, it is able to find an installed MiKTeX ...)

Comment: Thanks, I will try that